# Combinations using FOREACH in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, combinations

I would like to generate combinations in pig with the help of FOREACH. Is there any possible way to do this ?

```
My Input:
A
B
C

Objective:
A,B
A,C
B,C
```

Here's the sample which I have tried. This sample shows **" Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '$0'** ".

```
A = load '/test';
B = foreach A generate $0;
Combination = Cross A, B;
Combination_Filter = foreach Combination generate $0 < $1;
```

Please help me in resolving this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the below options?

**input:**

```
A
B
C
```

**Option1:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS(f1:chararray);
B = LOAD 'input' AS(f2:chararray);
C = CROSS A,B;
D = FILTER C BY A::f1 < B::f2;
DUMP D;
```

**Option2:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (f1:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1 AS (f2:chararray);
C = CROSS A,B;
D = FILTER C BY A::f1 < B::f2;
DUMP D;
```

**Output:**

```
(A,B)
(A,C)
(B,C)
```

Comment: I want the above result using foreach and not using filter. Anyway thanks for your response

Comment: @Edwin, foreach will not work in your case. You have to go for any of the mentioned approach(Filter or UDF).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that using only `foreach`, the only way to achieve something like that would be with Sivasakthi's answer, or using a custom UDF. You can put all the registers in a bag with a `group all`, and then run the UDF.

The UDF is in this other question: [How to turn (A, B, C) into (AB, AC, BC) with Pig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994246/how-to-turn-a-b-c-into-ab-ac-bc-with-pig)

The code would be something like:

```
A = load '/test';
A_grouped = group A all;
A_combinations = foreach A_grouped generate CombinationsUDF(A);
```